# wpf trigger not effective on style set in code

Tags: wpf, xaml, eventtrigger

In Resources.Xaml i set a style from Datagrid Cell

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger  Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

in a specific DataGrid Column i set the Foreground manually

```
 Sub New()
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
        Foreground = Brushes.Blue
 End Sub
```

when the cell is selected, the background dose change by the trigger, but the foreground dosen't

i believe that is it due to the fact that i set the forground in code

what can i do to solve this?

note: I cannot set the foregroud for the column in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing `Foreground = Brushes.Blue` you set local value for Foreground dependency property. Local value has higher priority than setter value from Trigger. I would advise to create a named style for DataGridCell, derived from based style, and apply derived style in code:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger  Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BlueCell" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

```
Sub
   CellStyle = (Style)datagrid.FindResource("BlueCell");
End Sub
```

I'm using c# syntax because of my lack of vb.net knowledge. Code calls `FindResource` method of DataGrid to retrive "BlueCell" style and after cast to `Style` type it is assigned to CellStyle of a column

Comment: @YonatanTuchinsky, great. feel free to suggest an improvement to this answer (suggest an "edit") if you had to change something significantly to make things work

Comment: I did what you suggested with few changes, igave the original style a key and based on that key - i also added it to the application Resouces.xaml and got the resources from there `Application.Current.Resources("NewStyle")`